# ui autocomplete formatting <li> results on 2 lines

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

Am using ui autocomplete from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote
Using PHP in search.php to return results.

Am trying to get my custom output of

```
<li>Company Name | Contact Name</li>
```

This is coming from the following code:

```
if(is_array($rs) && count($rs) > 0){
        foreach ($rs as $item) {
            //format: "Name Surname=>cid_uid"
            $json = array();
            $json['id'] = $item['parentCompanyId'].'_'.$item['uid'];
            $json['label'] = $item['companyName'] . ' | ' . $item['name'] . ' ' . $item['surname'];
            $data[] = $json;
        }
    }
```

This works fantstically well, however to make it easier to read results, I would like to rather have results on 2 lines within the < li > tags, so that its more like this:

```
<li>
Contact Name<br>
Company Name | Department Name
</li>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$json['label'] = $item['name'] . ' ' . $item['surname'] . '\n' .$item['companyName'];
```

and

```
$json['label'] = $item['name'] . ' ' . $item['surname'] . '<br>' .$item['companyName'];
```

and

```
$json['label'] = $item['name'] . ' ' . $item['surname'] . '\\n' .$item['companyName'];
```

All tries result in the list either showing the actual `<br>` tag or `\n` rather than pushing to the next line.

Viewing source with firebug shows `Name&lt;br&gt;Company`

Not sure if this is happening because of the:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Please note, my question is related to getting the HTML output to produce 2 lines within a `<li>` tag via autocomplete/php/json .. I'm not asking about how to add Department Name..Hope I'm making sense..

Ta

Comment: (FYI: "\n" doesn't do anything in HTML unless it's part of a textbox or textarea's value, or even a <pre> tag or possibly other tags...<br> is the one you want to visually put a line break in an HTML document)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override the `_renderItem` method:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete()
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( item.label )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

This demo from the documentation does the same thing: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

By default, `.append( item.label )` is `.text( item.label )` which is why your `<br />` gets replaced with `&lt;br /&gt;`

Comment: Legend, thank you! I tried to push the up arrow to reward but it says I need 15 rep rewards or summon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code also, if "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of" error is faced.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete()
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```