# jQuery: Autosuggest results parsed from XML and customize those parsed results

Tags: jquery, xml, autocomplete

I am retrieving some results from an XML file and on the autosuggest I am trying to add some html code as such:

```
London, <br/>
United Kingdom
```

My code is this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "veh.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function( xmlResponse ) {
                    var data = $( "geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
                        return {
                            value: $( "reg", this ).text() 
                                   + '<br/>'
                                   + $( "model", this ).text()
                        };
                    }).get();
                    $( "#mainsearch" ).autocomplete({
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 0,
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            log( ui.item ?
                                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", geonameId: " + ui.item.id :
                                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

and I get this result instead:

```
London,<br/>United Kingdom
```

I am trying to create a list effect.

My xml looks like this:

```
<geoname>
    <model>London</model>
    <reg>United Kingdom</reg>
    </geoname>


<geoname>
    <model>Paris</model>
    <reg>France</reg>
    </geoname>
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934193/ui-autocomplete-formatting-li-results-on-2-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this result :

```
London,<br/>United Kingdom
```

Because the default render use by the autocomplete was an `li` element and the data was just put in as text, not as html.

So, to change the render, you have to override the default render item and to add data in you item.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "veh.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xmlResponse ) {

        var data = $( "geoname", xmlResponse ).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $( "reg", this ).text() + '-' + $( "model", this ).text(),
                reg: $( "reg", this ).text(),
                model: $( "model", this ).text()
            };}).get();

        $( "#mainsearch" ).autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 0,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#mainsearch" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                     "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", geonameId: " + ui.item.id :
                     "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li class='ui-menu-item' role='menuitem'></li>" )
                   .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                   .append( "<a>" + item.reg + "<br />" + item.model +"</a>")
                   .appendTo( ul );
        };
    }
});
```

You have an example on the jQuery-UI Autocomplete presentation, with "custom data and display" : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Browse source of the demo and you'll find an other example.

Hope my answer could help you to solve part of your problem.

Comment: +1, pretty much what I would have done except I would have chained to the previous selector

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have hesitated, but for a better readability, i have decompose.

Comment: Thank you. There were 2 issues that I managed to correct. The one is that you've missed the + on the value line between - and model.this.
The other issue is that there are were no effects such as hover and clicking. I added the class ui-menu-item onto the <li> and the hover works fine. Now the issue is that I cannot click on an item.

Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast Sorry, just forgot `<a>` around the label you render. Just edit my post ;) Enjoy !

Comment: @palmplam To be honest, when I was trying to fix that issue myself, Ive tried that aswell and it is not that the issue im afraid so. It is something else.

Comment: According to the jquery demos, you've (and I) forgot the focus state. Edited your answer. Thank you